# P5.js or Javascript random value generation with no repeat

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to create 5 circle shapes with randomly generating filled color from an array. But since I hard coded 5 individual `random()` generation. Sometimes the randomly generated colors between the circles still being the same. I am not sure how to make it so the colors for each circles will not have same color (the same random result) :

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 700);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  filled = ['PapayaWhip','PaleVioletRed','Lavender','LightGreen','Coral', 'CadetBlue','Azure','HoneyDew','LightBlue','Thistle','SlateBlue','RosyBrown','SteelBlue','OrangeRed'];
  randcol1 = filled[floor(random() * filled.length)];
  randcol2 = filled[floor(random() * filled.length)];
  randcol3 = filled[floor(random() * filled.length)];
  randcol4 = filled[floor(random() * filled.length)];
  randcol5 = filled[floor(random() * filled.length)];
  fill(randcol1);
  circle(width/2,100,100);
  fill(randcol2);
  circle(width/2,200,100);
  fill(randcol3);
  circle(width/2,300,100);
  fill(randcol4);
  circle(width/2,400,100);
  fill(randcol5);
  circle(width/2,500,100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

By the way may I also ask, is there anyway to perform individual random generation without repeating 5 lines of `random()`?
Thanks

Comment: You can remove used values from `filled`

Comment: there is always a chance it will select the same color from your list...perhaps remove the chosen element

Comment: Just shuffle the array beforehand?

Comment: Oh ,yes! I didn't realize i can remove value from the array to solve the problem haha thanks.

Comment: @PeanutJams If you found a solution, please post an answer to your question, or consider deleting it.